# Stepper motor driver voltage question

Tags: driver, stepper-motor

Attempting to drive the stepper but noticed that the motor is rated for 3V 2A and both of these boards feature a motor driving voltage of 6-30V or 7-30V

Attempting to drive a Wantai 57BYGH420-2 Stepper motor.
I have these drivers at my disposal : 
Easy A3967 Stepper Motor Driver Development Board and
Big Easy Driver board v1.2 A4988 stepper motor driver board.

Can this be done while not damaging by stepper?

[Stepper](https://www.robotics.org.za/57BYGH420)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you stay below the 2A, it will be fine.  This is a common misconception about voltage ratings on stepper motors.

The 3V refers to how much DC voltage you could apply to a coil continuously.  The coil resistance is probably about 1.5Ω, so if you put 3V DC across a coil it would draw 2A.

The stepper driver will be sending pulses, so you don't actually need to worry about the voltage rating.

Comment: That answers everything, thank you. The driver board has a current limiting pot that I'll set.

Comment: @T-800_Frontendeng. - better stepper controllers control current by PWMing the supply voltage. By using a higher voltage, but changing the duty cycle of the drive, you can get get significantly faster control of the motor. Your Easy board is one of the good ones. Just set the current with the pot, and you can provide any supply voltage you like, within the stated limits.